# How to create a separate view in Storyboard to be included programmatically in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` that is fed with data from the local database. When the user first launches the app (after installing) the table view is empty and I display a `UIView` in the middle of the table view that contains a `UIImage`, a `UILabel` and a `UIButton` (a call to action).

The first version of this view I built programmatically, which was no good to me because every time I tweaked something I had to build the app again. Then I switched to the storyboard but had to drag a `UIView` to the middle of my `tableView`. It is working now but I don't like the way it is, I can't edit my table view cells without having to move the `UIView` out of the table view.

I'd like to have a way to build this view entirely separated from my tableView (or even from my view controller in question) and then reference it in the `viewDidLoad` call of my view controller.

Unfortunately Xcode does not allow us to drag views directly to the storyboard so I'm pretty lost here.

Please tell me if I haven't been clear enough. I appreciate any help you could give me.

**UPDATE**: It'd be particularly awesome to me if I could also create a custom Swift class for this view of mine and reference it in the storyboard. And then in my `viewDidLoad` I could simply instantiate my custom view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a XIB file in which you can drag a view (without a view controller).

In your code you can load the XIB using [`NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyXibName", owner:self, options:nil)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/index.html).

In the XIB file you can give the `UIView` a custom class (like you can do with view controllers in storyboard).

You then of course have to retrieve the view from the array returned by `loadNibNamed` and cast it to your custom class.